# How do I get response headers with RxAndroid + Retrofit in Kotlin?

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin, rx-android

I have an API observable returning a CUSTOM_MODEL.  I would like to get the response headers from this call too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your retrofit definition to return `Observable<Response<CUSTOM_MODEL>>`. The headers can be accessed through the `Response` object and `CUSTOM_MODEL` will be available through `Response.body()`.